# Usage of Server Side Controls in MVC Frame work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-4.0

I am using ASP.Net 4.0 and MVC 2.0 for an web application. As my project requiremrnt I have to use the server side control in my application which is not possibl in noraml case. Ideally I want to use AdRotator control and DataList control.

I saw few samples and references in CodePleax [MVC ControlLib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/)  howwver I found it is very less useful.

Can someone tell how to utilize theese controls in ASP.Net application along with MVC.

> **Note: Please provide functionalities related to the AdRotator and DataList
>   controls not the equivalent
>   functionalities**

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 1):

MVC pages do not use the normal .NET solution which makes use of normal .NET components almost impossible.

A normal .NET page use an event driven solution to call different methods service side but MVC use actions and view which are a completly different way to handle things.

Also, MVC does not use viewstate which most normal .NEt controlls require.

[Found this article discussing mixing of normal .NET and MVC.](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks for your reponse David. You are right, it is the idea of MVC. Basically it came for clean separation of Model, View and controller and to help TDD. However there are situation we can use Extended function to work with such this kind of situations. Simple example is Html.Grid() from telerik controls. So it is possible but how is the question? I guess my point make sense and please provide more off your view on this.

Comment: Any pure javascript controls shuld be usable as long as they do not require any normal .NET features but some might need some hacking to load since you do not have the normal page_load solution, unfortunatly I have very little experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

Base page for all the mvc views is derived from System.Web.Page.  So in theory you can use server controls in the views.

Some of these server controls work quite nicely in MVC framework.

For example following call renders the ads in an mvc view with out any problem.

```
<asp:AdRotator AdvertisementFile="ads.xml" runat="server" />
```

You will run in to issues if your controls need to post back to the server or need viewstate, otherwise I think they are safe to use. In all read-only rendering scenarios, I found these controls  safe to use

SiteMapPath, readonly Grid view, chart controls are other examples.

Comment: This seemed right but how to programmatically set "ads.xml" (in your example)?  The usual <%= syntax doesn't work.

Comment: <asp:AdRotator id="adRotator" runat="server" />
and in onload event set the value of  AdvertisementFile property of adRotator.